# open a file from shared,transfers background transfer

Tags: windows-phone-8

I´ve created a app that download a pdf file from a private server and store it in the "shared/transfers" directory. The point is: the pdf file is completely hidden, i cannot see the pdf that i´ve downloaded, neither the adobe reader app can recognize it

Comment: Are you sure the File is downloaded? What do you mean by `completely hidden`? What is the exact problem?

Comment: Yep iam sure the file is completely downloaded and also i don't get any erros the problem is i don't have access to the file and the background transfers inquire the download location '/shared/transfers" in the app not the isolated storage so i don't have any access to the file Yet i need to open it

Comment: Can you see the file using Windows Phone Toolkit? http://phone.codeplex.com/

Comment: actually no do you have any idea how to?

Answer (score 0):

I just opened the downloaded file with default launchers try this out

```
StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("Shared");    //I'm accessing the shared folder from LocalFolder
StorageFolder subfolder = await folder.GetFolderAsync("Transfers");    //Here i'm accessing transfers folder from shared folder
StorageFile bqfile = await subfolder.GetFileAsync("Your filname");    //here accesing the file from transfers folder.
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(bqfile);    // launching the file with default launcher.
```

I think this will suits your requirement.